# Modifying user inputed array elements.

Tags: python, arrays, user-input

I'm trying to write an array of 5 elements that are user inputted.
If the element is divisible by 5, 10 should be added to the element.
I have the basic code for the array:

```
p= [ 0 for i in range(5) ]
print ("Enter an integer number: ")
for i in range (5):
p[i]= int(input())
print ("The modified array is", p)
```

But I don't know how to modify (i)?

As far as I understand I have to use enumerate, but how s that applied to a input value?

```
for i,x in enumerate(p):
if x % 5 ==0 :
   p[i] + 5
```

But this does not modify the array at all? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You said "if the element is divisible by 5, 10 should be added" but you are adding 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the change made back into `p[i]`

```
for i,x in enumerate(p):
    if x % 5 ==0 :
        p[i] = p[i] + 5
```

You can change it while asking for input itself :

```
p=[]
for i in range(5):
    num=int(input())
    if(num%5==0):
        p.append(num+10)
    else:
        p.append(num)

# input : 1 2 3 4 5
# p : 1 2 3 4 15
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, thanks, but output is:    The modified array is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15] Why is range 10 elements instead of 5?

Comment: @WheatBall output is?

Comment: "The modified array is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15]"

Comment: Initialize `p=[]` not `p= [ 0 for i in range(5) ]`